# how to group by week in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I am using this sql to do a group by in MySQL 5.7, when I want to group by month:

```
select
    max(statistic_time) as statistic_time
    from home_overview_daily
    group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m')
    order by statistic_time desc
```

but when I group by week:

```
select
        max(statistic_time) as statistic_time
        from home_overview_daily
        group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%w')
        order by statistic_time desc
```

the result data look like this:

```
1640789999999   2021-12-3
1640703599999   2021-12-2
1640617199999   2021-12-1
1640530799999   2021-12-0
1640444399999   2021-12-6
1640357999999   2021-12-5
1640271599999   2021-12-4
1638284399999   2021-11-2
1638197999999   2021-11-1
1638111599999   2021-11-0
1638025199999   2021-11-6
1637938799999   2021-11-5
1637852399999   2021-11-4
1637765999999   2021-11-3
```

why the month 12 have 7 weeks? where am I doing wrong? I am using format like this `%Y-%m-%u`:

```
select
        max(statistic_time) as statistic_time,
        date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%u')
        from home_overview_daily
        group by date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%u')
        order by statistic_time desc
```

but the result like this:

```
1640789999999   2021-12-52
1640530799999   2021-12-51
1639925999999   2021-12-50
1639321199999   2021-12-49
1638716399999   2021-12-48
1638284399999   2021-11-48
1638111599999   2021-11-47
1637506799999   2021-11-46
1636901999999   2021-11-45
1636297199999   2021-11-44
```

every month have 5 weeks?

Comment: May be %w  means weekday number, not a week number you need?

Comment: what should I do to make it group by week? @Kondybas

Comment: Change format to `%Y-%m-%u` if week starts from Monday and to `%Y-%m-%U` if week starts from Sunday.

Comment: @Kondybas - you might like to write that up as an answer - I'd upvote it! To the OP, if `%u` or `%U` aren't suitable, there are some functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046729/in-mysql-how-to-return-the-week-of-the-month) (with some discussions) which you may or may not be interested in modifying to suit any particular needs you may have - HTH!

Comment: Week counting by `date_format` supposed that whole week having Sun|Mon in this month belongs to this month.

Comment: What do you want to do with the week that crosses a month or year boundary?  Which day of the week is the 'first'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Week numbers are controlled by `%u`, `%U`, `%v` and `%V` specifiers of the `date_format` format string. Returned value is in the range 0(1)-53. For grouping by week you need a date format like `%Y-%u`.

`%w` specifier is standing for daynumber within the week.

```
Sun = 0|7  
Mon = 1  
Tue = 2
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to look at weeks, ignoring year and month boundaries:

```
w = FLOOR((TO_DAYS(date_col) - n) / 7)
```

`n` is some number between 0 and 6, based on that day of the week is "first".

`w` is a week number.

Then work backward to find which date that week starts on:

```
FROM_DAYS(7 * w + n)
```

Example:

```
mysql> SET @n := 2;  -- for Monday being the "start of a week"
mysql> SELECT @w := FLOOR((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - @n) / 7);
+--------------------------------------------+
| @w := FLOOR((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - @n) / 7) |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                     105502 |
+--------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT FROM_DAYS(7 * @w + @n), curdate();
+------------------------+------------+
| FROM_DAYS(7 * @w + @n) | curdate()  |
+------------------------+------------+
| 2021-12-27             | 2021-12-30 |
+------------------------+------------+
```

(Don't use @ variables; they are used here for the convenience of demonstrating.)